# Best way to store auth credentials on fabric deploys?

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to learn how to quickly spin up a digital ocean / ec2 server to temporarily run a python worker script (for parallel performance gains). I can conceptually grasp how to do everything except how / where to store certain auth credentials. These would be things like:

git username / pass to access private repos
AWS auth credentials to access an SQS queue
database credentials
etc.

Where do I store this stuff when I deploy via a fabric script? A link to a good tutorial would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We have a local credential YAML file that contains all these, fab read the credentials from it and use them during the deployment only.